# Simple Linear Regression using Sklearn. Fit() is not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I am using this dataset:
https://filebin.net/wr2jy0ass7rsl0vt
There are three colums : "Date","Temperature","Anomaly" . I use "Date" to predict "Temperature". The code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

data_df = pd.read_csv("ave_yearly_temp_nyc_1895-2017.csv")


data_df.columns=  ["Date","Temperature","Anomaly"]

data_df["Date"] = data_df["Date"]//100

regressor = LinearRegression()

X_train,X_test, y_train,y_test = train_test_split(data_df.iloc[:,0],data_df.iloc[:,1],test_size=0.2, random_state=0)


regressor.fit(X_train,y_train) #training the algorithm
```

The data_df:

[image]

The error:

[image]

How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It needs a 2D array, using `iloc[:,0]` you are getting a 1D array.
Instead you can use the entire dataframe column as parameter.
Try using:

```
X_train,X_test, y_train,y_test = train_test_split(data_df['Date'],data_df['Temperature'],test_size=0.2, random_state=0)
```

Comment: I tried to reshape inside of regressor.fit(X_train,y_train). Is it possible? How to do it?

Comment: You can reshape using np.array(X_train).reshape(-1,1), but with this you need to reshape each one of the 4 arrays you created with train_test_split. Using the DataFrame column as parameter gives you a shorter and cleaner code, in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

Try to do what the error message tells you. It seems that the implementation expects X to contain more than only one feature. Hence you'll need to transform it like this:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(np.array(data_df.iloc[:,0]).reshape(-1, 1),data_df.iloc[:,1],test_size=0.2, random_state=0)
```

Comment: I tried to reshape inside of regressor.fit(X_train,y_train). Is it possible? How to do it?